# javascript regular expression not working

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms

I am trying to validate a textbox to ensure that a URL is written inside (minus the "http://" part). Here is my code:

```
var isUrl;
var regex = new RegExp("^(?!http)(www\.)?(([a-z])+\.[a-z]{2,}(\.[a-z]{2,})?)");
var siteUrl = e.target.value;
if (siteUrl.match(regex)) {
   isUrl = true;
}
else {
   isUrl = false;
}
```

So my regular expression is `^(?!http)(www\.)?(([a-z])+\.[a-z]{2,}(\.[a-z]{2,})?)`.
I was under the impression that this would do the following:

1. NOT match anything beginning with `http`.. which it **does correctly**
2. Allow an optional `www.` at the start
3. Accept 1 or more characters from a-z to be typed in
4. Accept a dot after those characters
5. Accept 2 or more characters following the dot, and
6. Allow an optional dot followed by two or more characters again.

In practice, the textbox accepts strings like "ashdiguasdf" and "aksjdnfa:://',~" which it should not do. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Use a regular expression literal or double escape using a constructor. Also, you don't need the Negative Lookahead if you're anchoring your pattern, you can omit that part and make sure you use the end of string `$` anchor as well.

Comment: I.e. use `var regex = /^(?!http)(www\.)?(([a-z])+\.[a-z]{2,}(\.[a-z]{2,})?)/i;` (I think case-insensitive matching is necessary here, thus I added `/i`).

Comment: Is this for very specific URLs? Are URLs without digits not allowed? Check this out - URL regex is way more complicated than expected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you're using the `\` character in a quoted string, which javascript will interpret as the start of a "control character" (such as `\n` for a newline, etc).

One option is to escape it by replacing `\` with `\\`.

But the easiest solution is to use the following format...

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^(?!http)(www\.)?(([a-z])+\.[a-z]{2,}(\.[a-z]{2,})?)/);
```

This also allows you to make it case insensitive (if you wish) by using the `i` character at the end, like this...

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^(?!http)(www\.)?(([a-z])+\.[a-z]{2,}(\.[a-z]{2,})?)/i);
```

---

As an extra bit, you're using more [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) than really necessary.  Your expression could also be written like this with the same result...

```
^(?!http)(?:www\.)?[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]{2,}){1,2}
```